# Performance of ON Clause over WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone please tell me Which of the following queries will have better performance?

```
SELECT 
      * 
FROM 
      [TABLE1] T1 
      INNER JOIN [TABLE2] T2 
      ON T2.[FK_ID] = T1.[PK_ID] 
WHERE 
      T2.[ACTIVE] = 1;
```

---

```
SELECT 
      * 
FROM 
      [TABLE1] T1 
      INNER JOIN [TABLE2] T2 
      ON T2.[FK_ID] = T1.[PK_ID] AND 
      T2.[ACTIVE] = 1;
```

Comment: As per me 2nd Query should be more efficient.

Comment: have to check with sql profiler

Comment: Test the performance of each and you'll know. Then go back and accept answers to some of your past questions.

Comment: My Table size is very small so i will not get much variation in execution time.

Comment: Then it doesn't really matter, does it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hpe this will give you answer : http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/850159-performance-conditions-where-clause-vs-conditions-inner-join

Answer (score 3):

They are identical: the optimizer is clever enough to work this out.

Not least, SQL is declarative so you're asking the optimizer for something but not telling it how to do it.

However, the first one is "correct" in that you are separating JOIN and WHERE.

Comment: +1 for difference between declarative versus... um apparently imperative according to Wikipedia.